# Ive just had a waterpump replaced on my 2014 tiguan a nd after1 hours drive it overheated

Tags: overheating, radiator, cooling

2014 vw tiguan, SUV, 2 litre petrol turbo, overheating, I've just had a waterpump replaced and after 1 to 2 hours drive it overheated, on short trips the two fans stay on for 1 to 2 minutes a after I stop the engine

Comment: what is the level of coolant in your radiator and reservoir,there have been some problems with leaking water pumps.

Comment: Have they bled it properly?

Comment: STOP driving it!  Overheating is VERY hard on the engine and you can cause serious and EXPENSIVE damage very quickly.  Get it checked at a shop immediately.  It's possible the water pump was not replaced properly or perhaps that was not the root cause of whatever issue caused you to seek to have it replaced in the first place.

Comment: Could be air in the cooling system. When they replaced the pump it obviously broke the cooling systems seal and introduced air in there. You're meant to "bleed" the air out of the system. The place to bleed is usually at the highest point in the cooling system - could be the radiator cap or a special valve (opened with a spanner) up near the engine. You're meant to run the car with this open (when its cold), topping the coolant up until all the air is forced out and you only see coolant near the top (with valve systems it will dribble out the valve).